# "Show windows stacked" in Windows 10 to use full screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

How to make the right click command menu on the taskbar "Show windows stacked" to stack the available windows on the whole screen, not just the 2/3 of it?

actually it does like this (see the second/right monitor)

[image]

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start → Settings → System → Multitasking.
2. Under Snap, turn off the third option which reads "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it." Then restart your computer.
3. After restart, it should now use the whole screen.